# Saving ringtone selection in Contacts app

Tags: contacts, backup, ringtone

My wife's Samsung Captivate (AT&T's Galaxy S variant) phone is running CyanogenMod 7.1 (Android 2.3.x). Several times for various reasons her Google account was removed and had to be re-added.  The problem is that each time her contacts were deleted from the phone, and in the process of being re-synced lost all customization, such as assigned ringtones.  Apparently syncing to Google Contacts doesn't save the ringtone selection, probably for a good reason.

Is there a way to preserve this info so that when contacts are deleted and re-synced she doesn't have to re-associate each one with a ringtone all over again?  Is there a way to do this via a 3rd-party app like Titanium Backup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Ringtone Keeper](https://market.android.com/details?id=ru.smithson.ringtoneKeeper&feature=search_result)** is also an free alternative that looks like it does what you want.

Comment: After years of back-and-forth, Ringtone Keeper is by far the best app for saving ringtones.

Answer (score 1):

**Mybackup** does not backup these ringtone assignments.

**Titanium** backs this up but it seems to assign to the wrong people after restore ([source](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ajVSxqKKlh1cJ%3aandroidforums.com/droid-all-things-root/252782-any-way-backup-ringtone-assignments-contacts.html%20titanium%20backup%20ringtone%20assign&cd=3&hl=no&ct=clnk&gl=no)).

**[Back My Tones Premium](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.indentapps.backmytones&feature=search_result&rdid=com.indentapps.backmytones&rdot=1)** looks like does what you want!

Comment: Thanks!  I'm trying Back My Tones Premium right now, will update with results.